# Flexslider count the slides on each slider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am using Flexslider to create several sliders on a page. It's a Wordpress so the posts are created dynamically. I'm counting the slides with the callback function and this line:

```
$('.promo-image-counter').text(slider.count);
```

but of course it changes the text on all of the image counters (all of the sliders show the number of slides from the last slider), I need to count the slides on each slider individually.

My code so far:

```
$(".slider-promos").flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav:false,
        touch:true,
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
          $('.promo-image-counter').text(slider.count);
          $('.slides li img').show();
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I have correctly count the slides on each slider with this code:

```
 $(".slider-promos").flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav:false,
        touch:true,
        slideshow: false,
        start: function(slider){
          $('.slides li img').show();
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
          $(slider).find($(".promo-image-counter")).text(slider.count);
        }
    });
```

Needed to use

```
$(slider).find($(".promo-image-counter")).text(slider.count);
```

instead of

```
$(this).find($('.promo-image-counter')).text(slider.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to count the slides on each slider individually.

You already do this, your failure is that you overriding the ".promo-image-counter" content with the count of the latest created slider instance. As you assume, you want this behaviour for each slider. You can reach this by selecting ".promo-image-counter"-element for each slider, something like this:

```
$('.slider1.promo-image-counter').text(slider.count);
```

Comment: The sliders are created dynamically, I cannot access the html and change their code.

Comment: Okay, can you show the html part where the element with the class ".promo-image-counter" is located?

Comment: It's normal HTML but it is repeated for every post there is. So imagine a page with 8 sliders all named the same but with different number of slides. It's a simple paragraph with the class of ".promo-image-counter". I think I should use the default callback functionality because it does not count the cloned slides so i don't really want to for example create a loop, count the slides and for each slide, etc.